# Is there a formula that would automatically insert a static date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using free version of 365
I would like to have today's date autofill in a1 when anything (a number) is entertered in b1.
need this date to be static and not change when I open the workbook on a different day.

Ive tried the date function but it changes the date when I open on another day.

Comment: Trust there are many articles online teaching you how to use VBA (macro) to achieve this.  Excel formula won't do that as it will be re-calculated in a live environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you would require some VBA to achieve the desired outcome, the following below will place today's date on A1 whenever the value on B1 is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Date
    'check if value in B1 changed and if so then update worksheet Sheet1 cell A1 = Date
End Sub
```